# CompareStr() function compares String with a Char?

Tags: delphi, string-comparison, delphi-10-seattle

I have this code below and want know if [`CompareStr()`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_CompareStr@string@string.html) can will work like this:

```pascal
    function xGetClassName(_Handle: HWND): String;
    var
      Buffer: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;
    begin
      GetClassName(_Handle, @Buffer, MAX_PATH);
      Result := String(Buffer);
    end;

    //...

    if CompareStr(xGetClassName(hWndWindow), #32768) = 0 then
```

Note that second arg in `CompareStr()` above is a **`Char`**.

Comment: Yes, CompareStr will work like this. It will turn the character constant into a string of one char. I am however not sure that you can find a menu (#32768 is a menu class name) this way.

Comment: Note that the documentation link is outdated. Use [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.CompareStr) instead.

Comment: Your `CompareStr` usage is wrong in this context. You need to compare the class name as a *String*. a simple `if xGetClassName(hWndWindow) = '#32768'` will do just fine.

Comment: @kobik: I couldn't check (at that moment), but that is what I thought to remember too. Hence my comment.

Comment: @BrowJr: note that the # syntax is something used in Delphi and some other Pascals. But Windows names are not in Pascal, so the # is the real character #.